# Aspose.zip error Unexpected end of data corrupted error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to compress several excel files, but when generate the excel it generates  corrupt. I don't know what could be any idea?

```
 var Clients = getClients();
  var carpetaUrl = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}/{2}.zip", IdCuenta, IdListado, "Folder");
            try
            {               
                using (MemoryStream zipFile = new MemoryStream())
                {
                 
                    using (var archive = new Archive())
                    {
                      foreach (var item in Clients)
                         {
                                 var (fileUrl, stream) = GenerateFileExcel(item.archivoNombre,item.IdClient);
                                 archive.CreateEntry(fileUrl, stream);
                        }
                        archive.Save(zipFile, new ArchiveSaveOptions() { Encoding = Encoding.ASCII });
                    }
                   
                      var uri = B.Azure.Storages.UploadFile("tttt", zipFile, carpetaUrl, false).ToString();
                     return uri;
                  
                }
```

Comment: Can you show code of the `GenerateFileExcel`?

Comment: this method  basically save the varialbe  XLWorkbook _book to  an  stream  and return 
            Stream fs = new MemoryStream();
            _books.SaveAs(fs);
            fs.Position = 0;
            return fs;